# php login script - remember me

Tags: php, mysql, oop, login-script

Can anyone see anything wrong with this login script:

```
public function login($username, $pass, $remember) {
  // check username and password with db
  // else throw exception  
  $connect = new connect(); 
  $conn = $connect->login_connect();      
  // check username and password
  $result = $conn->query("select * from login where
                          username='".$username."' and
                          password=sha1('".$pass."')");
  if (!$result) {
    throw new depException('Incorrect username and password combination. Please try again.');
  } else {
    echo $username, $pass;
  }
```

To explain:

At the moment the script is allowing anything through. In other words the query is returning true for any username and password that are passed to it. 
I've put the echo statement just as a check - obviously the script would continue in normal circumstances!

I know that the connect class and `login_connect` method are working because I use them in a register script that is working fine. depException is just an extension of the Exception class.
The function login() is part of the same class that contains register() that is working fine.
I know that the two variables ($username and $pass) are getting to the function because the echo statement is outputting them accurately. (The $remember variable is not needed for this part of the script. It is used later for a remember me process).
I'm stumped. Please help!

### UPDATE

Thanks for those responses. I was getting confused with what the query was returning. The complete script does check for how many rows are returned and this is where the checking should have been done. Everything is now working EXCEPT for my remember me function. Perhaps someone could help with that?!?! Here is the full script:

```
public function login($username, $pass, $remember) {
  // check username and password with db
  // else throw exception  
  $connect = new connect(); 
  $conn = $connect->login_connect();      
  // check username and password
  $result = $conn->query("select * from login where
                          username='".$username."' and
                          password=sha1('".$pass."')");
  if (!$result) {
    throw new depException('Incorrect username and password combination. Please try again.');
  }       
  if ($result->num_rows>0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    //assign id to session
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row[user_id];        
    // assign username as a session variable
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;        
    // start rememberMe
    $cookie_name = 'db_auth';
    $cookie_time = (3600 * 24 * 30);*/ // 30 days
    // check to see if user checked box
    if ($remember) {
      setcookie ($cookie_name, 'username='.$username, time()+$cookie_time);
    }
    // If all goes well redirect user to their homepage.
    header('Location: http://localhost/v6/home/index.php');   
  } else {
    throw new depException('Could not log you in.);
  }
}
```

Thanks very much for your help.

UPDATE 2!

Thanks to your help I've got the main part of this script working. However, the remember me bit at the end still doesn't want to work.
Could someone give me a hand to sort it out?
$username, $pass and $remember are all short variable names that I assigned before passing them to the function to save writing $_POST['username'] etc. everytime. $remember refers to a checkbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does `$conn->query()` return, a MySQL resource object like [`mysql_query()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) does? If so then it'll always compare "true". `mysql_query()` only returns `FALSE` if the query completely fails, like it has a syntax error or a table doesn't exist.

To check if you got any results you need to try to fetch a row from the result set and see if you get anything, via whatever your equivalent of [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) is.

**Important:** Your script is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://us.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), or even just odd usernames like `o'neil` with an apostrophe. You should escape all variables in a query with [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) (or equivalent) to make sure your query doesn't get messed up by special characters. Or, even better, use prepared statements which look like

```
select * from login where username=? and password=sha1(?)
```

---

**Re: UPDATE**

Variables from a form are available via either `$_GET` or `$_POST`, depending on which method was used to submit the form. Try `if (isset($_POST['remember']))` to see if that check box was checked.

**Important:** I see that you tried to use a bare `$remember` to see if the check box was checked. That suggests to me that you are trying to take advantage of the [`register_globals`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) feature in PHP which makes your GET and POST variables accessible via regular variable names. If that is the case you should heed the warning in the PHP manual!

> ### WARNING
>
> [`register_globals`] has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 6.0.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Use `$_GET` and `$_POST` instead. I could tell you how to make `if ($remember)` work, actually, but given the inherent evil-ness of `register_globals` I'm not gonna! ;-)

Comment: Could you give me more info or point me in the direction of a tutorial about protecting against SQL injection attacks and using prepared statements? Thanks!

Comment: muso - both John and I included links covering SQL-Injections.

Comment: Don't worry John, I haven't used register_globals. I assigned shorter names before passing the variables to the function:
$username = strip_tags(trim($_POST['username']));
$pass = strip_tags(trim($_POST['password']));
$remember = $_POST['rememberMe'];
Will you tell me how to fix it now?! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Your query is open for [sql-injections](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)...

> SELECT * 
>  FROM users 
>  WHERE
> username = '**' OR 'a' = 'a**' 
> AND password =
> sha1('**guessAnyPassword**')

I'd also check your result, and base the action on how many records were returned.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In php most queries only return False if there was an error executing them. Your query is returning a value, probably an empty array of values. This is not a false value as far as your if statement is concerned.

Check how many rows are returned. The function to do this will depend on your abstraction layer (connect class etc...)