# PHP is this code secure?

Tags: php

I found the following code [in a previous question on S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099846/php-login-script-remember-me)O. In following code, if the username and password supplied by the user is correct,  the user_id and username is stored in session to keep it logged. My question is, **why there is need to keep user_id in the session?** Isnt only one thing (for example, username) enough to store in session?
If the remember is enabled, then a cookie is set, only with username. **Now my question is, Is Only username cookie enough?** Can't anyone just edit or add the cookie in the browser and log in the system?

Thanks for your replies.

```
<?
public function login($username, $pass, $remember) {
    // check username and password with db
        $result = $conn->query("select * from login where
                            username='".$username."' and
                           password=sha1('".$pass."')");
        if (!$result) {
            throw new depException('Incorrect username and password combination. Please try again.');
        } 

       if ($result->num_rows>0) {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row[user_id];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

           // start rememberMe
            $cookie_name = 'db_auth';
            $cookie_time = (3600 * 24 * 30);*/ // 30 days

            // check to see if user checked box
            if ($remember) {
            setcookie ($cookie_name, 'username='.$username, time()+$cookie_time);
            }

            // If all goes well redirect user to their homepage.
            header('Location: http://localhost/v6/home/index.php'); 
            } else {
           throw new depException('Could not log you in.');
            }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Could we get some more informations about the context and the class it is referring to?

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli: My question is only related to storing the username in cookie if password is remembered. I was asking if it is sufficient and secure to remember only username, to keep user logged in. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**THIS CODE IS NOT SECURE!** (Sorry for the caps, but its for the emphasis). The SQL statement is susceptible to SQL injection. Also storing the username in the cookie is a bad idea because anyone can forge the cookie to gain authentication.

Comment: How else are you supposed to remember logins, if not with a cookie? I agree that storing the username and password in plain-text is a bad idea. But why not the hashed values? Surely any other cookie is just as susceptible to being forged - no?

Comment: @Charlie - but any site with a "remember me" feature uses cookies to remember the user... they can't all be insecure.

Comment: Sure, I understand that it is not secure, however, my question is only related to storing the username in cookie if password is remembered. I was asking if it is sufficient and secure to remember only username, to keep user logged in. Thanks.

Comment: @adam - no it is not secure to store the username in the password. You should be storing a hash of some kind that points to the username on the server.

Comment: @Nico Burns, don't you think that "any site" could have working something more complex out than just store username? Like hashes, salts, unique cookie id etc??

Comment: @Daniel A. White: Should i store username and hashed user ID, would that be sufficient? Thanks.

Comment: It should be something the server can reverse or lookup.

Comment: @Charlie - ah I see, its storing only the username which is insecure - thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

My answer to the question if this is secure: no.

You need to sanitize your code. What happens if someone enters 'test OR 1=1 ' as username?

Comment: Or ignoring sql injection, what's to say the cookie isn't hacked to say 'root' instead of 'joeuser'?

Comment: @Marc B: Exactly thats what my question is. What other information i should store in cookie with username, if not password. Thanks.

Comment: Don't ever send anything "sensitive" in the cookie. Instead, use a PHP session: `session_start()` will generate a unique token for you, which is sent out as the session cookie. You then store the username ON THE SERVER in the `$_SESSION` array, where the remote user can't tamper with it.

Comment: @Marc B: Can I keep the user logged in for some specific time using session, even if the browser is closed?

Comment: PHP's default handler is probability based, so if you need a specific timeout, you'd have to roll your own handler. Not too hard, but not trivial either. The session cookie is both a literal and figurative session cookie - by default it's supposed to be removed when the browser's closed. That can be changed via php config options, though.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really know where to start. This code is really unsafe.

- You should sanitize with
  `mysql_real_escape_string()` (or mysqli function, or even better: use PDO for any database connection and use prepared statements) the
  username and the password and be sure
  that `$remember` is either a boolean
  or an integer.
- The `sha1` is something like broken,
  so i'd suggest using `md5` instead.
- Cookies can be rewritten by the user
  that could add `username=admin` to
  the cookie and login as admin.

Comment: @corro, not at all... http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html

Comment: MD5 was first cracked in 1996. SHA1 wasn't broken until much later. I cannot stress this enough. Do NOT use MD5. Neither are secure. http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/836068 Take particular note to the recommendation.

Comment: I'm glad you are nowhere near my system.

Comment: You shouldn't be using either, that's the point. Both are compromised.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not secure.

Your data is open to SQL injection via the initial query, where depending on the access level of the database user, you could have anyone logging in. You need to sanitise your input.

Secondly, the access to the website via the cookie, and the username in it related to the access level and privilege they get? If so in it's current form the session can be easily hijacked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's A Code I use To Make Sure Everything Is Safe .. It may not be the safest but I also use other measures to verify a safe login. But this code will protect u against SQL injections.

```
function secure($data) {
    $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));

    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $data = stripslashes($data);

    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

    return $data;
}
```

It's usage

```
 secure($username);
```

for example

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $get[$key] = secure($value); 
}
```

This tells PHP  for each of the POST values secure it. 
You Can also use it for post by using $_GET instead of  $_POST but lets face it .. it would be really stupid to have your login using GET commands